# WebGL: Color not cleared on framebuffer with depth stencil texture attachment

Tags: javascript, webgl, framebuffer

I trying to draw objects with stencil enabled, and everything work fine. Below is the picture of animated frames (left to right) of the working result I expected.
[image: expected result]

The problem is occur when i am using framebuffer. From what I understand, WebGL 1.0 not support attach stencil separately with depth, neither from renderbuffer nor texture. It can be done by attach stencil and depth together via `WEBGL_depth_texture` extension. I am using that extension and use framebuffer, draw object, but the result seems not clear the color. Below is the picture of animated frames of the result.

[image]

Can someone explain what going on?

please explore the full code below.

```js
(function() {
var gl;
var dtExt;

var gProgram;
var gRectShader;

var gVertexAttribLocation;
var gColorAttribLocation;

var gRectVertexAttribLocation;
var gRectTexcoordAttribLocation;

var gModelViewMatrixUniform;

var gTriangleVertexBuffer;
var gTriangleColorBuffer;
var gQuadVertexBuffer;
var gQuadColorBuffer;
var gQuadTexcoordBuffer;

var gFramebuffer;

var gColorTexture;
var gDepthStencilTexture;

var rotationMatrix = mat4.create();

function initGL() {
 var glcanvas = document.getElementById("glcanvas");
 gl = glcanvas.getContext("webgl", {stencil:true});
 dtExt = gl.getExtension('WEBGL_depth_texture') || gl.getExtension('WEBKIT_WEBGL_depth_texture') || gl.getExtension('MOZ_WEBGL_depth_texture');
}

function initFramebuffers() {
 gFramebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();

 gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gFramebuffer);

 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gColorTexture);
 gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, gColorTexture, 0);

 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gDepthStencilTexture);
 gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, gl.TEXTURE_2D, gDepthStencilTexture, 0);

 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
 gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
}

function createTexture() {
 var texture = gl.createTexture();

 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
 gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
 gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
 gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
 gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);

 return texture;
}

function initTextures() {
 gColorTexture = createTexture();
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gColorTexture);
 gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

 gDepthStencilTexture = createTexture();
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gDepthStencilTexture);
 gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.DEPTH_STENCIL, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight, 0, gl.DEPTH_STENCIL, dtExt.UNSIGNED_INT_24_8_WEBGL, null);
 
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
}

function createAndCompileShader(type, source) {
 var shader = gl.createShader(type);

 gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
 gl.compileShader(shader);

 if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
  throw new Error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
 }

 return shader;
}

function createAndLinkProgram(glVertexShader, glFragmentShader) {
 var glProgram = gl.createProgram();

 gl.attachShader(glProgram, glVertexShader);
 gl.attachShader(glProgram, glFragmentShader);
 gl.linkProgram(glProgram);

 if (!gl.getProgramParameter(glProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
     throw new Error("Could not initialise shaders");
 }

 return glProgram;
}

function initShaderPrograms() {
 var gVertexShader = createAndCompileShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER, [
  "attribute vec3 a_vertex;",
  "attribute vec4 a_color;",

  "uniform mat4 u_modelViewMatrix;",

  "varying vec4 v_color;",

  "void main(void) {",
   "v_color = a_color;",
   "gl_Position = u_modelViewMatrix * vec4(a_vertex, 1.0);",
  "}"
 ].join("\n"));

 var gFragmentShader = createAndCompileShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, [
  "precision mediump float;",

  "varying vec4 v_color;",
  "void main(void) {",
   "gl_FragColor = v_color;",
  "}"
 ].join("\n"));

 gProgram = createAndLinkProgram(gVertexShader, gFragmentShader);

 var gVertexShader = createAndCompileShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER, [
  "attribute vec3 a_vertex;",
  "attribute vec2 a_texcoord;",

  "varying vec2 v_texcoord;",

  "void main(void) {",
   "v_texcoord = a_texcoord;",
   "gl_Position = vec4(a_vertex, 1.0);",
  "}"
 ].join("\n"));

 var gFragmentShader = createAndCompileShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, [
  "precision mediump float;",

     "uniform sampler2D u_sampler0;",

  "varying vec2 v_texcoord;",
  "void main(void) {",
   "gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_sampler0, v_texcoord);",
  "}"
 ].join("\n"));

 gRectShader = createAndLinkProgram(gVertexShader, gFragmentShader);
}

function initAttribAndUniformLocations() {
 gVertexAttribLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(gProgram, "a_vertex");
 gColorAttribLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(gProgram, "a_color");
 gModelViewMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(gProgram, 'u_modelViewMatrix');

 gRectVertexAttribLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(gRectShader, "a_vertex");
 gRectTexcoordAttribLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(gRectShader, "a_texcoord");
}

function initBuffers() {
 gTriangleVertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
 gTriangleColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
 gQuadVertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
 gQuadColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
 gQuadTexcoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gTriangleVertexBuffer);
 var vertices = new Float32Array([

      0.0, -1.0,  0.0,
     -1.0,  1.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  1.0,  0.0,

      0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
     -1.0, -1.0,  0.0,
      1.0, -1.0,  0.0,
 ]);
 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gTriangleColorBuffer);
 var colors = new Float32Array([
      0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 1.0,

      0.0, 0.0,  1.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 0.0,  1.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 0.0,  1.0, 1.0
 ]);
 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colors, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gQuadVertexBuffer);
 var vertices = new Float32Array([
     -1.0,  1.0,  0.0,
     -1.0, -1.0,  0.0,
      1.0,  1.0,  0.0,
      1.0, -1.0,  0.0
 ]);
 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gQuadColorBuffer);
 var colors = new Float32Array([
      1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
      1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
      1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
      1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
 ]);
 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colors, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gQuadTexcoordBuffer);
 var texcoords = new Float32Array([
      0.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 1.0,
      1.0, 0.0
 ]);
 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoords, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

}

function drawQuads() {
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gQuadVertexBuffer);
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(gVertexAttribLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gQuadColorBuffer);
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(gColorAttribLocation, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

 gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}

function drawRectQuads() {
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gQuadVertexBuffer);
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(gRectVertexAttribLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gQuadTexcoordBuffer);
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(gRectTexcoordAttribLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

 gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}

function drawTriagles() {
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gTriangleVertexBuffer);
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(gVertexAttribLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gTriangleColorBuffer);
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(gColorAttribLocation, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

 gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}


function renderScene() {
 var mvMatrix = mat4.create();

 gl.clearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);

 gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gFramebuffer);
 gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
 gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

 gl.enable(gl.STENCIL_TEST);
 gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
 gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);

 gl.clear(gl.STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

 gl.useProgram(gProgram);

 gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gVertexAttribLocation);
 gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gColorAttribLocation);

 gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
 gl.colorMask(false, false, false, false);

 gl.stencilFunc(gl.ALWAYS, 0, 0xff);
 gl.stencilMask(0xff);
 gl.stencilOpSeparate(gl.BACK, gl.KEEP, gl.KEEP, gl.INCR);
 gl.stencilOpSeparate(gl.FRONT, gl.KEEP, gl.KEEP, gl.DECR);

 mat4.identity(mvMatrix);
 mat4.scale(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]);
 mat4.multiply(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, rotationMatrix);

 gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gModelViewMatrixUniform, false, mvMatrix);

 gl.cullFace(gl.FRONT);
 drawTriagles();

 gl.cullFace(gl.BACK);
 drawTriagles();

 gl.stencilMask(0x00);
 gl.stencilFunc(gl.NOTEQUAL, 0, 0xff);

 gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
 gl.colorMask(true, true, true, true);

 mat4.identity(mvMatrix);
 mat4.scale(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, [0.75, 0.75, 0.75]);

 gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gModelViewMatrixUniform, false, mvMatrix);

 drawQuads();

 gl.disableVertexAttribArray(gVertexAttribLocation);
 gl.disableVertexAttribArray(gColorAttribLocation);

 gl.flush();

 gl.disable(gl.STENCIL_TEST);

 gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
 gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
 gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | gl.STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

 gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gColorTexture);

 gl.useProgram(gRectShader);

 gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gRectVertexAttribLocation);
 gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gRectTexcoordAttribLocation);

 drawRectQuads();

 gl.disableVertexAttribArray(gRectVertexAttribLocation);
 gl.disableVertexAttribArray(gRectTexcoordAttribLocation);

 gl.flush();
}

function step(timestamp) {
 renderScene();

 mat4.rotate(rotationMatrix, rotationMatrix, Math.PI / 360, [0, 0, 1])

    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

initGL();
initShaderPrograms();
initAttribAndUniformLocations();
initTextures();
initFramebuffers();
initBuffers();
window.requestAnimationFrame(step);

}());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.4.0/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>

<canvas id="glcanvas" width="480" height="360">
  WebGL not supported!
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the stencil mask before you clear the stencil buffer

```
gl.stencilMask(0xff);
```

Also, You don't need `WEBGL_depth_texture` just to make a depth+stencil attachment for a framebuffer. You can use a DEPTH_STENCIL renderbuffer

```
const rb = gl.createRenderbuffer();
gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, rb);
gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_STENCIL, width, height);
gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, gl.RENDERBUFFER, rb);
```

Also [multiline template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) would probably save you a lot of time.

Also `gl.flush` has no point in the code.